# Windows Server 2003 Server Edition - inside of Virtual PC 2007 SP1 - lost keyboard repeat, want it back

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtual-machines, virtualization, keyboard

I am using Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 SP1.  Inside this VM is Windows Server 2003 Server Edition.  I use it every day.  When I came into work, first day after the New Year's, and without changing any Windows settings, I lost the ability for my keyboard to repeat keys.

Yes, I can hold down any keyboard button and it will type it just once.  Outside the VM it works fine.

I did check Accessibility Options (Control Panel) -> Keyboard tab -> Settings button (for FilterKeys) -> Filter Options -> Settings button (for Ignore quick keystrokes ...).  The 'No keyboard repeat' radio button is not checked.

If I go to Keyboard (Control Panel), the Repeat rate is set to Fast.  The Repeat delay is closer to Short than Long.  If I actually go into the 'Click here and hold down a key to test repeat rate' textbox, and hold down a key - it does not repeat.

Again, outside the VM everything is fine.  My keyboard repeats on my host machine.  I've restarted that VM and shut it down multiple times.

What could be causing this?  How do I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the 25th (Jan), I noticed that my keyboard repeat was back (in my VM).  I have no idea why.

Previous to the 25th, I restarted the VM over and over again.  And now, I'm forgetting if I restarted my host computer (XP).

I installed some Windows Updates that day and restarted the host.  It was either the updates or the restart of the host (I'm guessing).  If it was a matter of restarting the host I'm mad because that's the first thing you should do when it comes to Windows!

Updates on the 25th (just for good measure):

Security Update for Windows XP
  (KB2584146)
  (KB2585542)
  (KB2598479)
  (KB2603381)
  (KB2618451)
  (KB2619339)
  (KB2620712)
  (KB2624667)
  (KB2631813)
  (KB2633171)
  (KB2639417)
  (KB2646524)

Hotfix for Windows XP
  (KB2633952)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what might have caused it, but you could click the radio button. Restart the VM, then unclick it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it, but no dice.  I'll up-vote for taking the time to help me.  Thanks, I appreciate it.